# main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jax-ws, mutual-authentication

I have a JAXWS client where I have configured the two properties for mutual authentication:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","sample.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","xxxx");        
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

From the logs, I see the following error at the end:

```
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I am not able to figure out the reason for this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which exact version of Java are you using ? Which ciphers did you enable ?

Comment: I am using Java 1.7. Do I need to add additional properties to enable anything?

Comment: There are known bugs in Java when it comes to support of ciphers, so you should give us the full version of Java you use: 1.70.nn. And as you enabled logging you should present us the log from both sides of the conversation.

Comment: Do you see a client certificate being sent?